# What index can be created for querying geograhy points within distance of another point?

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I am using postgresql.

The use case is straightforward: I got a many geography points represented by latitude and longitude. (the column type is `geography`, here is an example insert `INSERT INTO public.geo_table(geog) VALUES ('POINT(-122.121583 47.673918)');`)

Now, if I want to find all points within 1000m of point A `(-123.121513, 49.673988)`:

```
SELECT * FROM geo_table AS g
WHERE ST_DWithin(g.geog::geography, ST_MakePoint(-123.121513, 49.673988), 1000)
```

Is this a full table scan? If yes can I create an index for it?

Comment: Add the explain analyse to the question - you might see what's appropriate there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a spatial index on the geography column to avoid a full table scan:

```
CREATE INDEX geom_index ON geo_table USING GIST (geog);
```

You can check the query plan by adding `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before your query,
e.g.:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM geo_table AS g WHERE ST_DWithin(g.geog::geography, ST_MakePoint(-123.121513, 49.673988), 1000)
```

For more information regarding postgis geometry index see postgis documentation: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html